# calculating monthly mean and ensemble mean

Tags: nco

I have GLB_JJA_PRECT.nc contains JJA season climatological mean 1981-2010 for 205 members looks like:-
me@mali:/mnt/hgfs/t/data+plots/k$ cdo info GLB_JJA_PRECT.nc
-1 :       Date     Time   Level Gridsize    Miss :     Minimum        Mean     Maximum : Parameter ID
1 : 1981-07-09 22:41:52       0     3600       0 :  4.5667e-11  2.7681e-08  4.0864e-07 : -1
2 : 1981-07-09 22:41:52       0     3600       0 :  3.5674e-11  2.7657e-08  3.9481e-07 : -1
3 : 1981-07-09 22:41:52       0     3600       0 :  6.0882e-12  2.6316e-08  2.6459e-07 : -1
4 : 1981-07-09 22:41:52       0     3600       0 :  1.3473e-11  2.6756e-08  3.0247e-07 : -1
5 : 1981-07-09 22:41:52       0     3600       0 :  1.4372e-11  2.7102e-08  2.8263e-07 : -1
6 : 1981-07-09 22:41:52       0     3600       0 :  2.2106e-11  2.6214e-08  3.2279e-07 : -1
7 : 1981-07-09 22:41:52       0     3600       0 :  3.5954e-11  2.6145e-08  2.9494e-07 : -1
8 : 1981-07-09 22:41:52       0     3600       0 :  4.8026e-11  2.6042e-08  3.2751e-07 : -1
9 : 1981-07-09 22:41:52       0     3600       0 :  3.7863e-11  2.5948e-08  3.6591e-07 : -1
10 : 1981-07-09 22:41:52       0     3600       0 :  2.4222e-11  2.5728e-08  4.2891e-07 : -1
.
.
.
to  205

when i did splitstep,1 i got all 205 files, each file has same attr information and different var values
me@mali:/mnt/hgfs/t/data+plots/k$ cdo sinfo GLB_JJA_M_000001.nc
File format : NetCDF
-1 : Institut Source   T Steptype Levels Num    Points Num Dtype : Parameter ID
1 : unknown  GAMIL    v instant       1   1      3600   1  F32  : -1
Grid coordinates :
1 : lonlat                   : points=3600 (90x40)
lon : 0 to 356 by 4 degrees_east  circular
lat : -87.75 to 87.75 by 4.5 degrees_north
Vertical coordinates :
1 : surface                  : levels=1
Time coordinate :
time : 1 step
RefTime =  1975-01-01 00:00:00  Units = days  Calendar = 365_day  Bounds = true
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss  YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss  YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss  YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
1981-07-09 22:41:52

cdo    sinfo: Processed 1 variable over 1 timestep [0.02s 45MB].
me@mali:/mnt/hgfs/t/data+plots/k$ cdo info GLB_JJA_M_000001.nc
-1 :       Date     Time   Level Gridsize    Miss :     Minimum        Mean     Maximum : Parameter ID
1 : 1981-07-09 22:41:52       0     3600       0 :  4.5667e-11  2.7681e-08  4.0864e-07 : -1

i would like to calculating back the june, july and august monthly mean values 1981 - 2010 for each member, and also the monthly enseble of each month using NCO ??